# What does "confusing often rudimentary" mean in this context? It seems grammatically wrong.

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Direct observation of contemporary societies at the threshold of
>   widespread literacy has not assisted our understanding of how such
>   literacy altered ancient Greek society, in particular its political
>   culture. The discovery of what Goody has called the “enabling effects”
>   of literacy in contemporary societies tends to seduce the observer
>   **into confusing often rudimentary knowledge of how to read with popular
>   access to important books and documents**: this confusion is then
>   projected onto ancient societies. “In ancient Greece,” Goody writes,
>   “alphabetic reading and writing was important for the development of
>   political democracy.”

Can someone explain the bold part? The part "confusing often rudimentary knowledge" sounds grammatically wrong for me, and because of the part I cannot get the meaning of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*confusing often rudimentary knowledge* is not a discrete constituent

*Confusing* is the *-ing* form (gerund-participle) of the verb *confuse*, cast in the non-finite *-ing* form so that the clause which it heads can act as the object of the preposition *into*.

It is employed here in the construction *confuse A with B*, meaning "fail to distinguish A and B properly".

- The 'A' piece in this construction is the noun phrase *often rudimentary knowledge of how to read*. The head of this phrase is *knowledge*: it takes the complement *of how to read*, which designates what is known, and it is modified by the adjective *rudimentary*.

  *Rudimentary* in turn is modified by the adverb *often*; the sense is that on many (but not all) occasions the knowledge is merely rudimentary.
- The 'B' piece is *popular access to important books and documents*.

You may paraphrase thus:

> The discovery of the "enabling effects" of literacy today tends to mislead observers. They confuse the widespread ability to read, which is often merely rudimentary, with widespread access to important texts.

The author's point appears to be that ability to read at a minimal level does not assure that the reader will actually read complex texts, which require a much more sophisticated ability.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of an article, either "the" or "an," before "rudimentary" makes the sentence more readily understood. As it is, it's the kind of sentence even long-term speakers of English might trip over when reading aloud. Here it is with "an" inserted:

> The discovery of what Goody has called the “enabling effects” of
> literacy in contemporary societies tends to seduce the observer into
> confusing an often rudimentary knowledge of how to read with popular
> access to important books and documents ...

If allowed to use more words and some punctuation in the service of yet more clarity, one could substitute "a society's" for my "an," for this result:

> The discovery of what Goody has called the “enabling effects” of
> literacy in contemporary societies tends to seduce the observer into
> confusing a society's (often rudimentary) knowledge of how to read with
> popular access to important books and documents ...